# What react lifecycle component to use to update state after an axios post

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into a challenge when setting the state after Axios makes a post.

Doing this

```
   this.setState({
       image_url:response.data.img_url,
    // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
   })
```

Does not set the state immediately, So when running this code

```
   this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
       <Grid item md={8} key={i}>
       {/* <Image image_url={this.state.image_url}/> */}
             <Image img_url={img} />                   
       </Grid>
   ))
```

No item gets updated, just an empty array.

So im forced to use something similar to `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state as soon a user uploads a file. However my attempt is ignoring the `componentWillReceiveProps` method. I'm not able to see the console.log within the method

Using `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillUpdate` gives an error

> ERROR: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls

What should i do ?

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import Image from './Image';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            image_url: 'http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg', 
            images: []
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file => {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        data.append('ourImage',image)
        data.append('name', image.name)
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                image_url:response.data.img_url,
                // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
            })
        });
        console.log(this.state.image_url);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState){

        this.setState({
            images:[nextProps.images, this.state.image_url ]
        })
       console.log(this.state.images);
        // if(prevState.images && prevState.images.length){

        // }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} md={6} style={{ margin: '40px 0px', padding: '0px 30px'}}>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Welcome to the Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                        <ImageUploader
                            withIcon={true}
                            withPreview={true}
                            buttonText='Upload an image'
                            imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                            onChange={this.handleUpload}
                            maxFileSize={5242880}
                        />
                    {this.state.images.length > 0 ? (
                        this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
                            <Grid item md={8} key={i}>
                                {/* <Image image_url={this.state.image_url}/> */}
                                    <Image image_url={img} />                   
                            </Grid>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Grid item md={8}>
                                <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Grid>
                {/* Images  */}
              </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`. The props don't change due to a `setState` call, so `componentWillReceiveProps` won't get called.

In order to avoid an infinite loop, you should compare `image_url` from the current and previous states, and only call `setState` if they're different:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.image_url !== prevState.image_url) {
    this.setState({
      images: [nextProps.images, this.state.image_url]
    });
  }
}
...
```

The reason is that calling `setState` triggers a re-render, which calls `componentDidUpdate` again, which calls `setState` again, etc etc... so you need to short circuit it by *not* calling `setState` unless the state/props are different.

Comment: this doesn't work, like i posted react ignores the componentWillRecieveProps function.

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood the issue you were running into. You should be using `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`, I've updated my answer to reflect this. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for explaining, this is what im looking for.

Comment: oh yeah its supposed to be nextProps in the first argument.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! According to the React docs, it's `prevProps`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Your constructor does not invoke props in its declaration or super. That might be why it is ignoring componentWillReceiveProps.